# spring @Value injects as is

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

I have an external properties file that holding sql queries like this

```
--- sql.properties --- 

sql.user.getAll=select * from user
sql.user.create=insert into user(username, password) values (:username, :password)
sql.user.get=select * from user where username=:username

...
```

Now, when I try to get these with @Value like this

```
@Repository
@PropertySource( "classpath:sql.properties" )
public class JdbcUserDAO {
   @Value("${sql.user.get}")
   private String sql_getUser;
}
```

Here `sql_getUser` gets the exact value `${sql.user.get}` so It obviously does not parse the file I specified. Something I'm missing ?

Comment: Have you read the javadoc of `@PropertySource`?

Comment: Are you aware that your sql.propertiesfile should be at the root of your classpath to make this exercise work?

Comment: it finds the file alright. @SotiriosDelimanolis is right it says it supposed to be used with `@Configuration` funny I've already read it and missed it. So I need another class with @Configuration for that as well?

Comment: That and a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` bean.